# Put the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 so the total of each row, column and diagonal add up to the same number

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Puzzle for grade 11 foundations of mathamatics course thank you in advance for the help 
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has answered...

```
6 1 8
7 5 3
2 9 4
```